# Copying a triple nested container

Tags: c++, iterator, hashtable, nested-loops

I have a data structure that I'd like to make an exact copy of within a function. For example, x is already filled and I'd like to make y an exact copy.

```
std::vector<std::list<std::pair<T,K>>> x; // T and K are template parameters
std::vector<std::list<std::pair<T,K>>> y;
```

Due to its nested nature, I'm confused as to what the correct syntax would be. I have this so far but it is obviously incomplete as I am not sure how to access the first and second members of pair within the list at each vector index.

```
for( int i = 0; i < xSize; i++){
    for( auto iter = x[i].begin(); iter != x[i].end(); iter++){
        // copy x into y here
}
```

Would someone mind helping me think through what I need to do? Thanks.

Comment: Since `pair` is not a container, you don't have a "triply-nested container".

Comment: Nope.  Standard containers do that for you.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

To make it so that `y` is exactly equal to `x`, use the following code:

```
y = x;
```

Comment: Umm...Would this still work if T or K are of pointer type? I mean, sure the address would be copied but then the pointers in 'x' and 'y' would point to the same location.

Comment: @vishal-wadhwa: Yes, of course, and I would expect two copies of a pointer to point at the same thing. That's what makes them "copies".

Answer (score 0):

simply with the following:

```
y = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

If **T** and/or **K** are user defined types and contain any pointers then you need to overload assignment operator for that types (follow rule of 5). Rest is on STL, because STL's containers had their implementations of = operator, and as others mentioned, just doing "y = x;" would be enough.